# json and null value

Tags: java, android, json

I can't understand why this code is crashing, I have this response from my server:

```
    [{
        "parking1": "Plaza de la Estacion",
        "parking2": "",
        "takeDate": "2012-12-11 11:00:48",
        "returnDate": null,
        "time": null,
        "cost": "0.00"
    }]
```

I convert this into a `JSONObject` and check if `returnDate` is null:

```
JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
if (json_data.getString("returnDate") == null) {
}
```

But this condition is never true. How should it be checked if null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if a json entry is null using:

```
if(json_data.isNull("returnDate")) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
if (json_data.opt("returnDate") == null) {
}
```